# How to disable email modification in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to disable user modification of their email account after registration in Moodle 3.1.7

I tried this with no luck https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=169041

Comment: Settings > Site Administration > Plugin > Authentication > Manual accounts. and locking the email field won't work?

Comment: No, I tried in all kind of settings for accounts, even disabling that field in all sections.

Comment: Are you talking about this? https://i.imgur.com/FjYk4xA.png ? This worked for me.

Comment: Yeah, I disabled email in all kind of modules and the issue still persists

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator, you have to go to the manual accounts authentication manager.

Here you have the option to **lock** profile fields, so the user can't edit them. **This option is only available to users you created manually as administrator or created *via upload* with a CSV file.**

Go to the corresponding section:

> Settings > Site Administration > Plugin > Authentication > Manual
>   accounts.

And choose the [locked value between the 3 available](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Managing_authentication#Profile_fields_data_mapping_and_locking) according to the official docs.

> Lock value: To prevent users from altering some fields (e.g. students
>   changing profile information to inappropriate or misleading
>   information), the site administrator can lock profile fields. It's
>   usually a good idea to lock profile fields if you are maintaining this
>   data in the external authentication system.

- **Unlocked**: The field is unlocked and can be edited by the user at any time.
- **Unlocked if empty**: The field is unlocked if it is empty, but once the user fills in some information, it becomes locked and cannot be edited any more.
- **Locked**: The field is locked and cannot be edited by the user.

You can choose to apply this to any of the following fields:

- First name
- Surname
- Email address
- City/town
- Country
- Language
- Description
- Web page
- ID number
- Institution
- Department
- Phone 1
- Phone 2
- Address

Here is a screenshot of the section:

[image]

[Source for image and part of the instructions](http://www.xelium.co.uk/2015/06/lock-user-profile-fields-in-moodle/)

Comment: Did you check the notice regarding user creation? This probably won't work if the users auto provision their accounts. You should check the corresponding authentication module if using other than manual.

Comment: Leo, I disabled email in all kind of modules and the issue still persists. I created an user just to test it out.